# Brackets can't find Chromium in Windows

Tags: chromium, adobe-brackets

I have Chromium from [chromium.woolyss.com](http://chromium.woolyss.com) but Brackets cannot find it for Live Preview. Should I make a type of Chrome symlink to Chromium?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File -> "Enable Experimental Live Preview" makes it work.

Comment: doesn't work for me. Did you use installer and archive (portable) version of chromium at woolyss.com?

Comment: I used the installer. This was a year ago tho, and I don't even use brackets anymore.